# send gps notification from everywhere

Tags: android, notifications, gps

I have a list of coordinates (30+ pairs of longitudes-latitudes) and my task is the following:

I should create an android application which sends a notification (on the statusbar) to the user if he/she is on one of the 30 places that my list contains. The notification part is ready, i can do this in an activity (iterating through the list, if coordinates equal, then send the notification, but how can I do this for all activities, and for those times when the app is in cache, but not open? Thanks

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(AGPS.this, SecondClass.class);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(AnotherGPS.this);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondClass.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent
                    .FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(AnotherGPS.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cam_icon)
                            .setContentTitle("My notification")
                            .setContentText("content of notification")
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context
                    .NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NM.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are building below api26 you can use background service to listen for location changes, provided your application has permission and the location of mobile is on

Starting api 26 services will not work that way and you most likely get some exceptions, for doing background tasks you have to go through this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#abll

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this in a Service and not in the Activity
take look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025303/4705092

in `onLocationChanged` compare locations and if it fits you call notification part